unable to connect physical device with android studio in ubuntu
I am trying to connect my android mobile with android studio  but it is not showing on devices list i have checked for all the option like open usb debugging or select file transfer in connection option but still facing same problem.
If I try to access device storage from file explorer it shown a error dialog says :-
Unable to open MTP device ("001,007"
My device is working file till yesterday for I don't know what has happened this time.
Can anyone help me.
I have tried by restarting my system as well as mobile device and tried with 2 other android devices too but still having the same problem.
